# After deleting Linked List it is still printing

Tags: c, linked-list

I was practicing linked list:
even after deleting list using `deleteList()` function, my `printList()` function is still printing whole list, here is my code, what is wrong in my code? is it problem in delete function declaration or function calling, is there any error in my `main()` and `printList()` function?

I searched the Internet and tried code from tutorial sites also.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void deleteList(node **head);   
void printList(node *head);

int main(void) {
    node *prev, *head, *p;
    head = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        p = malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("Enter number\n");
        scanf("%i", &p->data);
        p->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
            head = p;
        else
            prev->next = p;
        prev = p;
    }
    deleteList(&head);
    printList(head);
    free(p);
    return 0;
}

void printList(node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("\nNULL\n");  
    } else {
        printf("\n%i", head->data);
        printList(head->next);
    }        
}

void deleteList(node **head) {
    node *cur = *head;
    node *nxt;

    while (cur != NULL) {
        nxt = cur->next;
        free(cur);
        cur = nxt;
    }
    *head = NULL;    
}
```

Comment: you sure ? it's showing null for me

Comment: did you compile again your code after adding the deleteListe ?

Comment: `free(p);` seems to double free (as last allocated `p` value is stored as part of the list) and causes UB. You should make `p` local to loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is mostly correct:

- There is an extra `free(p);` at the end of `main()` causing undefined behavior because the node is already freed by `deleteList()`.
- you should check the return value of `malloc()` and `scanf()` to avoid undefined behavior in case of failure to allocate memory or failure to convert an integer from the input stream.

Apart from these problems, the code should always print `NULL` after freeing the list.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void deleteList(node **head);   
void printList(const node *head);

int main(void) {
    node *head = NULL;
    node *prev = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        node *p = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (p == NULL)
            return 1;
        printf("Enter number\n");
        if (scanf("%i", &p->data) != 1)
            return 1;
        p->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
            head = p;
        else
            prev->next = p;
        prev = p;
    }
    deleteList(&head);
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}

void printList(const node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("NULL\n\n");
    } else {
        printf("%i\n", head->data);
        printList(head->next);
    }
}

void deleteList(node **head) {
    node *cur = *head;

    while (cur != NULL) {
        node *nxt = cur->next;
        free(cur);
        cur = nxt;
    }
    *head = NULL;    
}
```